# Can't connect MySQL and Web

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

I do some coding to connect MySQL and webserver. This is my coding

```
$dbusername = "root";  // enter database username, I used "arduino" in step 2.2
$dbpassword = "qonita84";  // enter database password, I used "arduinotest" in step 2.2
$server = "localhost"; // IMPORTANT: if you are using XAMPP enter "localhost", but if you have an online website enter its address, ie."www.yourwebsite.com"

// Connect to your database

$dbconnect = mysqli_connect($server, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
$dbselect = mysql_select_db("LTKA",$dbconnect);

// Prepare the SQL statement

$sql = "INSERT INT LTKA.angkot (RFID_ID, Saldo, KM) VALUES ('".$_GET["ID"]."','".$_GET["sisa"]."','".$_GET["naik"]."')";

// Execute SQL statement

mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

When I want to push some data to the database using Google chrome, it's always show this message

> ```
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
> HTTP ERROR 500
> ```

Here is what I put in the address column
https://localhost/write_data.php?ID=GH23658I&sisa=5000&naik=1

Can someone give me solution?

Comment: Your sql is missing an O after INT.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain a little bit about that? I'm still new on MySQL

Comment: "INSERT INT LTKA.angkot"  should be "INSERT INTO LTKA.angkot". Not going to be the problem though.

Comment: I had change the code into INSERT INTO. But it still showing the same problem. ~Thank you

Comment: To debug this, put a statement `echo $sql;` right before the `mysql_query` and comment out the `mysql_query`. Copy the SQL statement that appears on the screen. Now log into your database with the `mysql` command line query and execute that statement. Does that help?

Comment: Your mysql server is running? Check with ps -aux | grep mysqld and check if port 3306 has any listenning  service with lsof -i -P -n | grep 3306 . You should run both commands with sudo or as root user.

Comment: Thank you all.. I've solved this problem by changing  each part of mysq_... to mysqli_..

Answer (score 0):

Wrong argument sequence here:

```
$con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_database,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
```

Look at the message: Access denied for user `'exuser'@'IP_Remote'` (using password: YES) where `root` is not a user, it is your database's name as set above `$mysql_database = "***********_people";.`

Solution:

```
$con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
```

And Grant permission for User:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO exuser@'IP_REMOTE' IDENTIFIED BY 'Exuser2019!' with grant option;
flush privileges;
```